# Postgres: how to upsert while ignoring primary key?

Tags: python, postgresql, hash

Am trying to store records in a database from a source system whose data changes infrequently.  Would like to only store a new record when data has changed.  For example, consider a Postgres table with an integer primary key and three fields, `a,b,c,`

```
id, a, b, c
-----------
1  foo bar baz
```

If our source system provides the following updates

```
(foo, bar, baz)
(foo, bar, baz)
(foo, bar, bazinga)
```

Then the DB should be updated only with the changed record

```
id, a, b, c
-----------
1  foo bar baz
2  foo bar bazinga
```

Am having trouble finding a straightforward way to enforce this.  ***Is this something the DB can manage or does the application have to do it?***

My first thought was an upsert.  Is it possible to do an upsert where one specifies only the fields that are relevant to the change?  Can the upsort ignore the pk/ID field?

Another approach would be to compute hash of incoming values based on certain fields and then storing as an additional column.  Then new writes would only have to compare hash field.

```
id, a, b, c, hash
-----------------
1  foo bar baz, jl23l8s
2  foo bar bazinga, xl39la2
```

If went this way, should the application be responsible for hasing records or can DB handle this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL can handle this with a `unique` constraint and `on conflict` upsert.

```
alter table my_table add constraint uq_my_table_a_b_c unique (a, b, c);
```

Then for the upsert:

```
insert into my_table (a, b, c)
on conflict on constraint uq_my_table_a_b_c do nothing;
```

Based on your comment, you want to allow duplicates of `(a, b, c)` just not consecutive ones (presumable in order of `id`).

You can use this for your insert:

```
with last_rec as (
  select a, b, c
    from my_table
   order by id desc
   limit 1
)
insert into my_table (a, b, c)
 select 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
 except
 select a, b, c from last_rec;
```

Comment: Actually - this has one issue.  It's possible that an updated row can have values of an older row.  We just want to ensure there's been a changed row between them.  In that cause, this would fail right?  Because the unique constraint applies to all rows not to just the last row, yes?

Comment: @AdamHughes  Yes.  This will fail at the point of creating the constraint.  You will need to use a trigger to make this happen.  If you have complete control over the insertion of records into the database, you can do this with a CTE.